# Android, Expandable list item issue

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying form last 2 days to display the expanded list item left side.[image]

By default list is expanding down, i want to change this style, i want to display only 1 item click on level 1, Please guide me how to change the style or anybody have any good idea..
Please guide me.. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

There's no single style parameter you can adjust to make it like that.

One way to implement it would be to have two (non-expandable) listviews side by side and set the content of the right one based on the item the user selects in the left one.

Comment: when clicking on list item then can we get the x, y co-ordinate of list item?

Comment: Typically you would listen for click events on a list cell with an OnItemClickListener. This would give you the position in the list (index of the cell).
I don't think you need x,y coordinates based on your description of the problem, but if you do, you could have a look at OnTouchListener.